# What will happened to my WETH TOKEN if the receiver or the network didn't support WETH TOKEN

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, ether, contract-debugging, smart-contract-wallets

I send WRAPPED ETH to a wallet/network which is COINS PH WALLET that has supported ETH ADDRESS, i thought WETH and ETH are the same? Now my problem is how can i possible retrieve my TOKEN?

Comment: WETH is an ERC20 version of the native ETH coin. Support depends on the intervening parties. WETH isn't part of the Ethereum specification, is just a contract deployed by a third party. Coins ph seems to be an exchange. Unfortunately, they define their own rules which tokens they accept or not. If the exchange refuses to help you should contact local authorities for customer protection.